# I want to create an object to be used for drawing a 3D surface in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, 3d, surface

I'm trying to create an object to draw a 3D surface based on that,

```
tmp <- matrix(10:39, nrow = 3, ncol = 10)
x <- 10:12
y <- 20:30
```

tmp[x,y] is the z

How should I create such an object?

Comment: You can use `plotly`: https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/

Comment: What do yo mean by _tmp[x,y] is the z_?

Comment: Just a variable

Comment: I knew about ploty, the problem is how to create the data object to pass it to plotly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
library(plotly)

tmp <- matrix(10:39, nrow = 3, ncol = 10)
x <- 10:12
y <- 20:30


plot_ly(x = x, y = y ) %>% 
  add_surface(z = t(tmp)) #transpose it
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I have a hard time understanding why we should transpose tmp. Assume z is f(x,y) what's the best way to form an object to pass it to plot_ly for a 3d plot in x,y,z space?

Comment: @Mehdi Zare plotly looks at the columns of a the z matrix as it was x and rows as it was y: z ~ f(y, x). You can check out `data(volcano)` and [this](https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/). volcano matrix has 87 rows and 61 column and the range of y values corresponds to rows and the range of x values corresponds to columns.  In fact for a surface plot one does not even need to specify x and y variables, just pass a z matrix to `add_surface`.